How to get custom eslint working on Visual Studio 2022?
My package.json
{
    ...
    "main": "index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "18.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^9.9.1",
        "globals": "^15.3.0"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {}
}

Then i have on the root folder a file .eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = 
{
    "env"                   : 
    {
        "browser"           : true,
        "es2021"            : true
    },
    "extends"               : "eslint:recommended",
    "globals"               : 
    {
        "global"            : "writable",
        "isObject"          : "readonly",
        ...
    },
    "overrides"             : 
    [
        {
            "env"           : 
            {
                "node"      : true
            },
            "files"         : [ ".eslintrc.{js,cjs}" ],
            "parserOptions" : 
            {
                "sourceType": "script"
            }
        }
    ],
    "parserOptions"         :
    {
        "ecmaVersion"       : "latest",
        "sourceType"        : "module"
    },
    "rules"                 :
    {
    }
}

and eslint.config.js
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";

export default [
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
];

I have isObject on another .js file as
globalThis.isObject = function(value)
{
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value))
        return true
    return false
}

I dont know whats happening, looks like its ignoring the eslintrc.cjs file, because everywhere i  have isObject(...)
eslint is throwing  'isObject' is not defined., this also happens with any other variables i define on the "globals" array.
My nodejs project is working correctly, just the eslint errors.
Without the file eslint.config.js eslint doesnt detect anything.
I have also tried on package.json:
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "./.eslintrc.cjs"
    }

and
    "eslintConfig": {
        "overrideConfigFile": "./.eslintrc.cjs"
    }

Similar question for VS 17/19 but the option on the accept answer no longer exists on VS22.
